# Retrieving the Principal in a RESTful WebApi method

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, formsauthentication

I am new to RESTful services using WebApi.  I have a front-end web application that uses FormsAuthentication to authenticate users.  I am able to use the `User.Identity` property without any problems in my MVC controller methods.

However, I want to use Angular to make Ajax calls from the browser to the Restful methods in WebApi.  The problem occurs with the user principal in these methods - `HttpRequestMessage.GetUserIdentity()` always returns null.  By contrast, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in these methods correctly returns the currently authenticated user identity.  My WebApi controller is decorated with the `Authorize` attribute.

What am I missing that is stopping `GetUserIdentity()` from working?  Here is my controller.

```
[Authorize]
public class CategoryController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ICategoryJson> Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var user = request.GetUserPrincipal();                  // returns null
        var user1 = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;   // returns authenticated user identity

        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my Ajax call.

```
$http.get("/api/Category", config).then(function (response) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(service.list, response.data);
    service.listLoading = false;
});
```

Comment: at what point are you calling this method in your API? HttpRequestMessage.GetUserIdentity()

Comment: I have added code to my question

Comment: The right way to get is: user = this.User; User property from ApiController provide Principal for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC controller inherits from a different base class so that's why it works in the MVC controller and not the Web API.

In Web API 2 you can use RequestContext.Principal or as you have used the Thread.CurrentPrincipal within your controller action to get the users Identity.

I don't think this issue is related to the ajax or angular call. you can try calling the same MVC controller action from the angular code and it should still return the user's identity.